# Comparison across unique readers

Tags: r, dataframe

**Reprex**

```
dat <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4), 
                  reader = c(1,4,2,3,3,4,2,5), 
                  response = c("CR","PR","SD","SD","PR","PR","CR","SD"))
```

**Problem**: Wish to compare `response` across each unique `reader` for each `id`. There are 5 unique `readers` in total, but each `id` only has 2 individual `readers`.

The resulting dataset would look something like this:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 4
     id read1 read2 matchflag
  <dbl> <chr> <chr>     <dbl>
1     1 CR    PR            0
2     2 SD    SD            1
3     3 PR    PR            1
4     4 CR    SD            0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
dat <- data.frame(id, reader, response) 
dat %>% 
  select(-reader) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(obs = seq_along(id)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from="obs", values_from="response", names_prefix="read") %>% 
  mutate(match_flag = as.numeric(read1 == read2))

# # A tibble: 4 x 4
# # Groups:   id [4]
#      id read1 read2 match_flag
#   <dbl> <chr> <chr>      <dbl>
# 1     1 CR    PR             0
# 2     2 SD    SD             1
# 3     3 PR    PR             1
# 4     4 CR    SD             0
```

Answer (score 3):

A `data.table` option

```
dcast(
  setDT(df),
  id ~ paste0("reader", rowid(id)),
  value.var = "response"
)[
  ,
  match_flag := +(reader1 == reader2)
][]
```

gives

```
   id reader1 reader2 match_flag
1:  1      CR      PR          0
2:  2      SD      SD          1
3:  3      PR      PR          1
4:  4      CR      SD          0
```

Answer (score 1):

A slight change from @DaveArmstrong's solution is also by creating the row sequence with `rowid` (from `data.table`, and then pivot to wide format and create the new column by using a relational operator and coerce to binary with `+`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(data.table)
 dat %>% 
      transmute(id, obs = rowid(id), response) %>% 
      pivot_wider(names_from = obs,values_from = response, names_prefix = 'read') %>%
      mutate(match_flag = +(read1 == read2))
# A tibble: 4 x 4
#     id read1 read2 match_flag
#  <dbl> <chr> <chr>      <int>
#1     1 CR    PR             0
#2     2 SD    SD             1
#3     3 PR    PR             1
#4     4 CR    SD             0
```